# fetching data from the result set in java

Tags: java, mysql

i am trying to fetch the max data of a column from my java code, but i get an error at the result set

my code is as shown below

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb123","root","root");

LOGGER.info("connected to the database");
Statement stmt0 = conn.createStatement();           
String qr= "INSERT INTO stumarks " + "VALUES ("+null+","+marks+")";
Statement stmt1 = conn.createStatement();
stmt1.executeUpdate(qr);
String countQuery = "select MAX('seqNum') as count1 from stumarks";
ResultSet res = stmt0.executeQuery(countQuery);
LOGGER.info("result set success!!"); 
int num = res.getInt("count1");``
System.out.println(num);
```

Comment: As general style advice, it's much better to use parameterized queries than concatenating strings to make a query (faster, clearer, less error-prone), and constants such as `count1` should generally be moved into constant variables (`public static final`) instead of being embedded into your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before trying to get the value

```
int num = res.getInt("count1");
```

you need to call [ResultSet#next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29) (and check that it returns true) to access the first row of the result set

```
if (rs.next()) {
    // Do what you want
    int num = res.getInt("count1");
    System.out.println(num);
}
```

To keep iterating over the result set, you can use the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

The result set has described in the Javadoc begins at index -1.
`.next()` should be called once to get the first result.

> Initially the cursor is positioned before the first row.

From a security point of view, you should avoid appending variable to your request but instead use parameters (SQL Injection matter)

Also don't forget to `close` your `connection` and `statement` to avoid `Out of memory` and to avoid taking all your DB connection slots. You can close the result set (good practice) even if it's not required using JRE classes :

> A ResultSet object is automatically closed when the Statement object that generated it is closed, re-executed, or used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of multiple results.

Answer (score 0):

The Java `ResultSet` is a *cursor*; it logically points to a particular position within the results of some query. From the Javadocs:

> A `ResultSet` cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the first call to the method next makes the first row the current row; the second call makes the second row the current row, and so on.

You're trying to read from the `ResultSet` while it's still pointing above the top of the list (the position `beforeFirst`). To advance the cursor, call `res.next()`, which returns a boolean indicating whether there are more rows. If you want to print the results from several rows, use a `while` loop like this:

```
while(res.next()) {
    System.out.println(res.getInt("count1"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use like:

```
"INSERT INTO stumarks VALUES("+null+", "+marks+")";
```

good practice to use `prepareStatement()` method to insert,delete and update.

and use resultset like:

```
if(rs.next)
{
   int num = res.getInt("count1");
}
```